# Independence between Uniform distribution and Exponential distribution question

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem and I am having a *great* deal of difficulty in a number of areas. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Let me state the problem first.

> If $X$ is uniformly distributed over (0,1) and $Y$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $ \lambda = 1$, find the distribution of $(a)$ $Z=X+Y$ and $(b)$ $Z=X/Y$. Assume independence.

Here is what I have so far:

$X$ is a uniform distribution so we know it has a density function of $f(x) = 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$. $Y$ has a density function of $f(y)=e^{-y}$ for $y \ge 0$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, their joint density function is $f(x,y) = e^{-y}$.

Now I have the solutions but my main question is this:

For part $(a)$, we have to find $P( X + Y \le a)$. But then there are $2$ integrals, one for $a>1$ and one for $a<1$. Why is that? Please do not go through the trouble of solving the integral, it is more important for me to understand where the limits of integration come from.

On the other hand, in part $(b)$, we have to find $P(Y>X/a)$. Where did this come from? I thought we have to find $P(X/Y \le a)$ which is the same thing as $P(Y \le a/X)$ ... In creating this equation, what determines the inequality sign for parts $(a)$ and $(b)$.

Once again please do not solve the integral!!

Thank you so much! I am very confused :/ Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, ask yourself what is the range of $Z=X+Y$? Since it can take any value in $(0,\infty)$, you seek
$$
P(X+Y\leq z) \, \quad \text{for } z\in (0,\infty)
$$
You can do the integral d$x$d$y$ or d$y$d$x$, I prefer the later one as it saves us from doing an integration by part. As you said, the density is $e^{-y}$.

Rewriting $P(X+Y\leq z)=P(Y\leq z-X)$, the probability seeked is
$$
\int_0^z \int_0^{z-x} e^{-y}dydx.
$$
However you need to take in consideration the range of $X,Y$. For $z>1$, the integral becomes 
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{z-x} e^{-y}dydx,
$$
since $X\in(0,1)$.

For your second question, you only made a slight mistake. You seek
$$
P(X/Y\leq z)=P(X\leq Yz)=P(X/z\leq Y)
$$
Either of the last two forms will work, once again I prefer the latter because it is easier to integrate.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand my silly mistake for the second part. I also realize that $x \in (0,1)$. so if $z>1$, then we can only allow $z=1$? Since $x \in (0,1)$? I think I understand! At least it made sense in my head! Thank you :)